# NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "@angular/common/http"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular6

i have created a new project using visual studio and upgraded to angular6 from angular4. after upgrading i am facing **" Error: Cannot find module "@angular/common/http" "**

tried importing **httpclientmodule** but no luck

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AppShippingNotice",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.1.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "css": "2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "2.0.5",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.16.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.3",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.3.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2"
  }
}
```

App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { ShipLogComponent } from './components/shiplog/shiplog.component';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ShipLogComponent

    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,      
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,        
        Ng2SmartTableModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'ShipLog', component: ShipLogComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

my componenet

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppService } from '../../services/appservices';
import { shippingnotice } from './shiplog.modal';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';




@Component({
    selector: 'ShipLog',
    templateUrl: './shiplog.component.html',
    providers: [AppService]
    //styleUrls: ['./app/components/request/request.component.css']
})

export class ShipLogComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(public userService: AppService, http: HttpClient) { }
    public ArrApiLi: shippingnotice[];
    public GridData: any;
    public  errorMessage: string;
     settings = {
        columns: {
            id: {
                title: 'ID'
            },
            name: {
                title: 'Full Name'
            },
            username: {
                title: 'User Name'
            },
            email: {
                title: 'Email'
            }
        }
    };

   data = [
{
            id: 1,
            name: "Leanne Graham",
            username: "Bret",
            email: "Sincere@april.biz"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Ervin Howell",
            username: "Antonette",
            email: "Shanna@melissa.tv"
        },

        // ... list of items

        {
            id: 11,
            name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
            username: "Nicholas.Stanton",
            email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz"
        }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
      // this.userService.getApiList().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); this.ArrApiLi = data; });

    }



}
```

whenever i run the app it shows error. HTTPModule is already declared and imported.

need help !!!

Comment: Did you run `npm i` ? Did you restart your `ng serve` ? What did you try to correct this issue ?

Comment: Does your`node_modules` folder contains angular/common/http ?

Comment: deleted Node_module folder and re installed.
upgraded typescript
and yes angular/common/http is there in node_modules

Comment: i created this project using visual studio 2017 built-in template.